# Prompt user before the session ends

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to display a dialog box where it shows the remaining time for the current session to expire. I have implemented it, unfortunately,the timer is ticking multiple times.Here is my code.

`warningTime` and `timeout` value is fetched from the api which is in parent component.

```
const [ remainingTime, setRemainingTime ] = useState(warningTime);

    useEffect(() => {
        let interval = null;
        if (timeout > 0) {
        let sessionTimeoutInterval = setInterval(() => {
            let runTime = localStorage.getItem("timeout");
            if (parseInt(runTime) === warningTime) {
                openDialog();
                if(remainingTime===warningTime) {
                    interval = setInterval(() => {
                        if (remainingTime > 0) {
                            setRemainingTime(remainingTime => remainingTime - 1);
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
                if(remainingTime === 0) {
                    handleDialogClose();
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            } else{
                localStorage.setItem("timeout", --runTime); 
            }
        }, 1000);
        if (remainingTime === 0) {
            handleDialogClose();
            handleLogout();
        }
        return () => {
            clearInterval(sessionTimeoutInterval);
        };
        }
    }, [timeout, remainingTime, warningTime ]);
```

`remainingTime` will be displayed in dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made couple of change in the code.

1. I am using `useRef` to hold the status of the component. So in `useEffect` i am checking if the component is mounted and then setting the timer value from the `localStorage` or from the `props` value and on subsequent updates `useEffect` will not execute the code inside `if (init.current)` block.

> useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component
>
> Note useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes. Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render.

2. I am using `setTimeout` to update the `sessionTimeout` state after every 1 second to update the timer, so the state update will execute the `useEffect` hook after each update as the `sessionTimeout` in included in the `useEffect` dependency.

Try this.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import DialogBox from "./DialogBox";
import Logout from "./Logout";

export default function Child({ warningTime, timeout }) {
  const [showDialog, setShowDialog] = useState(false);
  const [showLogout, setShowLogout] = useState(false);
  const [sessionTimeout, setSessionTimeout] = useState(timeout);
  const init = useRef(true);
  const progressbar = useRef(warningTime);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (init.current) {
      init.current = false;
      let sessionTime = localStorage.getItem("timeout");

      if (sessionTime && sessionTime < warningTime) {
        progressbar.current = sessionTime;
      } else {
        progressbar.current = warningTime;
      }

      if (sessionTime) {
        setSessionTimeout(prevState => sessionTime);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("timeout", sessionTimeout);
      }
    }

    let sessionTimeoutInterval = null;
    if (sessionTimeout > 0) {
      sessionTimeoutInterval = setTimeout(() => {
        if (sessionTimeout <= warningTime) {
          openDialog();
        }
        setSessionTimeout(sessionTimeout => {
          let updatedtime = sessionTimeout - 1;
          localStorage.setItem("timeout", updatedtime);
          return updatedtime;
        });
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem("timeout");
      handleDialogClose();
      handleLogout();
      clearTimeout(sessionTimeoutInterval);
    }
    return () => {
      if (sessionTimeoutInterval) clearTimeout(sessionTimeoutInterval);
    };
  }, [sessionTimeout]);

  function openDialog() {
    setShowDialog(true);
  }

  function handleDialogClose() {
    setShowDialog(false);
  }

  function handleLogout() {
    setShowLogout(true);
  }

  function addMoreTimeHandler() {
    handleDialogClose();
    setSessionTimeout(sessionTimeout => {
      localStorage.setItem("timeout", timeout);
      return timeout;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {showLogout ? <Logout /> : "Time remaning: " + sessionTimeout}
      {showDialog ? (
        <DialogBox
          progressBar={progressbar.current - 1}
          sessionTimeout={sessionTimeout}
          addMoreTime={addMoreTimeHandler}
        />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Live Example**

[image: Edit Prompt user before the session ends]

Comment: I need to display the `remainingTime` in dialog box.

Comment: replacing `setInterval` with `setTimeout` is not working

Comment: nope, not getting any error, but it executes only once. i.e., dialog is not triggered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207288/discussion-between-codezombie-and-sohail).

Comment: Given example is resulting in infinite loop and not able to close the dialog box.if an user refreshes the page then the remaining time should be shown instead of initial value.

Comment: Yeah, its working as expected for now.We will chat if necessary.Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried to simulate your code with dummy data and it worked.

let [ remainingTime, setRemainingTime, sessionTimeout, warningTime] = [1000, 5000, 10000, 1000];
let runTime = 3000;

   function abc() {
        let interval = null;
        if (sessionTimeout > 0) {
        let sessionTimeoutInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (parseInt(runTime) === warningTime) {
                // openDialog();
console.log("open dialog");
                if(remainingTime===warningTime) {
                    interval = setInterval(() => {
                        if (remainingTime > 0) {
                            remainingTime -= 1000;
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
                if(remainingTime === 0) {
                    // handleDialogClose();
console.log("close dialog");
                    clearInterval(interval);
clearInterval(sessionTimeoutInterval);
                } 
            } else {
if(runTime > 0){ // this condition is newly added
                runTime-=1000; }
            }
        }, 1000);
        }
    }
abc();
```